# Mysql GROUP BY and Union based on date condition

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Here is my query - it mostly works, but I can see it failing on one condition - explained after the query:

```
$firstDay = '2020-03-01' ;
$lastDay = '2020-03-31' ;
SELECT * FROM clubEventsCal 
            WHERE ceFreq!=1
              AND (ceDate>='$firstDay' AND ceDate<='$lastDay') 
  UNION SELECT * FROM clubEventsCal 
            WHERE ceFreq=1
              AND (ceDate>='$firstDay' AND ceDate<='$lastDay') 
  GROUP BY ceStopDate ORDER BY ceID,ceDate ;
```

The first select gives me all Event records between the two dates.  The second select gives me grouped/summarized Event records between the two dates.  The problem though is if the value `ceDate` spans days across two months:  IE: 2020-03-30 thru 2020-04-02.  When I pull the records for March, all is good - the above query pulls the 2020-03-30 record (grouped) as the first instance of the 4 days/records - allowing us to charge for a single 4 day event.  But when I pull the records for April its also going to pull `2020-04-01` as a new grouped Event record for the last two days of the 4 day event and try to charge the customer for a new Event - when in fact those two days were already a part of March's bill.

How can I write the query so that when ceDate starts in Month X but ends in Month Y that when records are pulled for Month Y its not trying to pull records that actually belong to an Event that started in Month X?

Examples of an Event record would look like this:

```
rid | ceID  | ceActive   |   ceFreq   |  ceDate    | ceStopDate
------------------------------------------------
1    1108         1            3        2020-03-09 | 2020-03-09   
2    1111         1            2        2020-03-15 | 2020-03-15   
3    1112         1            2        2020-03-17 | 2020-03-17   
4    1117         1            1        2020-03-30 | 2020-04-02   
5    1117         1            1        2020-03-31 | 2020-04-02
6    1106         1            3        2020-03-21 | 2020-03-21   
7    1110         1            2        2020-03-05 | 2020-03-05   
8    1113         1            2        2020-03-24 | 2020-03-24   
9    1117         1            1        2020-04-01 | 2020-04-02
10   1117         1            1        2020-04-02 | 2020-04-02
```

The above query pulls all records where `ceFreq != 1`, and it pulls a single  record for the `ceFreq = 1` records (rids: 4 & 5).  For March, we don't necessarily care that ceID 1117 spills into April.  But when we pull records for April - we need to exclude rid 9 & 10, because the Event (ceID=1117), was already accounted for in March.

Comment: could you post the SQL scripts to create your table and populate it with data, and also clarify what the query returns now compared to what you want it to return. It's not really clear what the query returns now based on the result set you posted and the description of the result set

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM clubEventsCal 
...
GROUP BY ceStopDate
```

This is gibberish.

MySQL (depending on configuration) allows it without choking - but it's semantically wrong and stands out as an anti-pattern.

There are some edge cases where the values returned might contain significant data, but they very unusual. Trying to explain a problem with code which does not work is perhaps not a good strategy.

Looking at your code, its possible that you don't need a union - but there's not enough information in your example records to say if this would actually give the result you expect (it will be significantly faster depending on your indexes):

```
SELECT IF(cefreq=1, rid, null) AS consolidator
, ceid
, cefreq
, MIN(cedate), MAX(cedate)
, ceStopDate
FROM clubEventsCal 
WHERE cID=1001 
  AND ceActive!=2
  AND (ceDate>='$firstDay' AND ceDate<='$lastDay') 
GROUP BY IF(cefreq=1, rid, null)
, ceid
, cefreq
, ceStopDate
;
```

I would have added the ORDER BY - but I don't know where `clId` came from. Also This will give different resuts to what I think you were trying to achieve for any record where `cefreq` is null (if you really do want to exclude them, add a predicate in the WHERE clause).

Comment: @symbcbean - after looking at my original post I realize it was poorly written.  I simplified the query fields and added more records to elaborate on the records and issue.  Hopefully it makes more sense now.